# How to fully refresh vim in windows

Tags: vim

How to refresh vim? We know we can refresh Visual Studio Code by deleting `.vscode` in `C:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming` and `code` folder from `C:\users\<username>`,  and it completely removes vscode data. So I wanna move to vim now, but I am thinking what if I need to fully refresh vim. So can someone please tell me the way to fully refresh vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see where Vim looks up for things in the output of `:version`:

```
[…]
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
[…]
```

Doing `:echo $HOME`, `:echo $VIM`, and `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` *in Vim* will print out the value of each environment variable.

In general, `$VIM` (and `$VIMRUNTIME`, which is a subdirectory of `$VIM`) is to be considered *off limits*. That directory is handled by the installer and Vim itself will never write anything there so you can basically forget about it: during usage, Vim is only going to write files in `$HOME`, `C:\users\<username>` on Windows.

> what if I need to fully refresh vim

Everything you do to customise Vim (settings, plugins, whatever) must happen in `$HOME\vimfiles\`, which a) makes it easy to move your config around, and b) is in *your* `$HOME`, as all *your* stuff should be. Deleting that directory or renaming it to something else should make it invisible to Vim, and thus nullify all your settings, and thus revert Vim to its pristine state.

Additionally, you will have to delete the following files:

- `$HOME\_viminfo`, which Vim uses to keep registers, marks, etc. between sessions, see `:help viminfo`.
- Swap files, see `:help swap-file`.

Aaand that should do it.

Now… while certainly doable and easy, wiping one's config to start again from scratch is likely to be a sign that one got ahead of themselves out of excitement. It is not something one usually does, especially if one invested their time properly into:

- `:help vimtutor`, first,
- and then, as instructed at the end of `vimtutor`, `:help user-manual`, which is a very easy to follow and comprehensive tutorial that will do a much better job at teaching one how to use Vim than all the videos, posts, threads, answers, and tweets one might come across *combined*.